# How do I add map markers to a separate class file?

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, kotlin

In android studio I've created a map with hundreds of markers on it. I want to separate these into individual classes and put them in a separate package, so that there isn't one massive list of markers in my main code. Is there a way of doing this? I'm using Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

so what I think you are trying to say is.
There is an Activity let's say MainActivity and it has maps in it and has let's say some 200 markers on it.

and all are individually initialized and assigned and you want to club them all together so that you'll be able to use them just by searching for one.

if that's the case, what I would suggest is.

make a separate Data Class that stores Marker and other data related to it.

```
data class MarkerInfo(
  //marker ID
  val id:Int,
  //marker Data
  val markerData:Marker,
  //other Data
  var otherData:String
)
```

now coming to storing and accessing data.

```
class MainActivity(){

  //at the top level, inside Activity
  // This will create an empty list of Marker Info
  var markerData = mutableListOf<MarkerInfo>()

  //Now take any function, let's say x
  private fun x(){
  //Mark a Marker on Map and assign it to a variable.
  val markerA : Marker = map.addMarker( MarkerOptions.position(somePosition))

  //we assign a function with id and other relevant data
  val x= markerData.size
  
  //store data in list
  markerData.add(MarkerInfo(x, markerA, "This is a very useful marker"))
 }
}

//now to access that marker.
//let's say there is a function named y.
private fun y(){
  //say we want to access the first marker
  //there are two ways to do so.

  //first method: you know some data which is already in there let's say we know id
  for(i in markerData){
  if(i.id == 1){
   Log.d("TAG", i.toString())
  }
 }
  //second method: directly
  Log.d("TAG",markerData[0].toString())
}
```